# iterate the dataframe with the given string using python

Tags: python, pandas

I've a cli argument

```
import os
import sys

month_year = ''
if sys.argv[1:]:
     month_year = sys.argv[1]

print(month_year)
>python file.py 202012,202101,202102
```

Now `month_year will be 202012,202001,202102   class <'str'>`

Also I've a dataframe

```
city            sales         
Los Angeles     2000
Florida City    1000
```

How can I append `month_year` as a column to the above dataframe, so that every record in df is mapped to every year in that string?

```
city            sales         year
Los Angeles     2000          202012
Florida City    1000          202012
Los Angeles     2000          202101
Florida City    1000          202101
Los Angeles     2000          202102
Florida City    1000          202102
```

Answer (score 0):

With a DataFrame, you can simply assign a value to a new column. (DataFrame is assigned to `df`):

```
           city  sales
0   Los Angeles   2000
1  Florida City   1000
```

```
df["year"] = month_year  # where `month_year` == "202012"
```

```
           city  sales    year
0   Los Angeles   2000  202012
1  Florida City   1000  202012
```

With that, your `month_year` output can be leveraged to create a full listing like you want.

```
full_df = pd.DataFrame()

for year in month_year.split(","):
    year_df = df.copy()
    year_df["year"] = year
    full_df = full_df.append(year_df)
```

```
           city  sales    year
0   Los Angeles   2000  202012
1  Florida City   1000  202012
0   Los Angeles   2000  202101
1  Florida City   1000  202101
0   Los Angeles   2000  202102
1  Florida City   1000  202102
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dataframe for the years, give each a common, temporary key and then merge the 2 dataframes, dropping the key in the process.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

month_year = ''
if sys.argv[1:]:
     month_year = sys.argv[1]

print(month_year)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['key']=0

df_years =pd.DataFrame({'year':month_year.split(',')})
df_years['key']=0

df = df.merge(df_years, how='outer').drop(columns='key')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your starting df is the one with two rows, this should work:

```
l = ['202012','202101','202102']
df2 = pd.concat({i:df for i in l}).reset_index(level=0).rename({'level_0':'year'},axis=1)[['city','sales','year']]
```